# Analyzing shell sort algorithm (big O)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

This is the shell sort algorithm.

```
  void shellSort(int array[], int n){
    for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){
        for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {
           int temp = array[i];
           int j;

           for (j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap){
              array[j] = array[j - gap];
           }
           array[j] = temp;
        }
      }
  }
```

I'm certain that the outer loop of this algorithm runs **logn** times but I'm not sure with the  middle loop and the innermost loop. This site https://stackabuse.com/shell-sort-in-java/ said that the middle loop runs **n-gap** times while the innermost loop runs **i/gap** but I'm not so sure about that. Please help me understand how the middle and innermost loop runs in this algorithm, thank you so much for anyone helping me this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the loops in the algorithm:

```
for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2) {
  for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {
    for (j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap) {
    }
  }
}
```

Let's start with loop over `i`. It starts at `gap` and goes to `n` with increment of 1. The next loop over `j` starts at current `i` and goes down by `gap` until it becomes smaller than `gap`. So, the loop over `j` executes once for `i` between `gap` and `2*gap`, twice for `i` between `2*gap` and `3*gap`, three time for `i` between `3*gap` and `4*gap` and so on.

That means that the `j` loop will execute once for `gap` different values of `i`, twice for `gap` different values of `i`, three times for `gap` different values of `i`, etc.

The maximum value for `i` is `n`, so the loop over `j` can execute at maximum `j_max = (n - gap)/gap` times. Total number of executions of the `j` loop is

```
1+1+...+1+1 + 2+2+...+2+2 + 3+3+...+3+3 + .... + j_max+j_max+...+j_max+j_max
|_________|   |_________|   |_________|          |_________________________|
 gap times     gap times     gap times                    gap times
```

This sum is equal to

```
gap*(sum from 1 to j_max) = gap * j_max(j_max + 1) / 2 = O(gap * ((n-gap)/gap)^2) = O((n-gap)^2/gap)
```

This will be repeated for different values of `gap` in the outer loop, so the complexity is O-big of

```
sum((n-gap)^2/gap, for gap = n/2, n/4, n/8, ...., 4, 2, 1)
```

Expanding:

```
(n^2 - 2*n*gap + gap^2)/gap = n^2*(1/gap) - 2*n + gap
```

The first term is equal to `n` squared multiplied by the following values:

```
1/(n/2),  1/(n/4),  1/(n/8), ..... 1/4,  1/2, 1/1
```

or

```
2/n, 4/n, 8/n, ....., n/n
```

This is a sum of powers of two divided by `n`, so the first term gives in total

```
n^2/n * 2^(log2 n) = n^2
```

The second term is `-2*n` summed `log2 n` times, so complexity is

```
n*log2 n
```

The last term is sum of `gaps`, so it's sum of powers of two and its complexity is `n`.
Combining all together we get the worst case complexity as O(n^2).

Comment: Thank u so much for ur time, this helps me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration, the middle loop starts at gap and ends at n. So the total number of iterations would be **n - gap**

The inner gap starts at i. In each iteration, it gets reduced by gap.
Suppose i = 15 and gap = 3, then values of j in subsequent iterations would be 15,12,9,6,3. Which is 5 iterations. Therefore **i/gap** iterations in the worst case.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for finding number of terms in an arithmetic sequence is 
(last term - first term) / difference + 1

`for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1)` 
starts at i = gap and exits when i == n. Last value i can take is n - 1.

Every loop, i is incremented by 1, so this loop gets executed (n - 1 - gap) / 1 + 1 = n - gap times

`for (j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap)`

This loop starts at j = 1 and exits when j < gap (ignore the second part by assuming worst case senario). The last value j can take is gap.

Every loop, j is decremented by gap, so this loop gets executed (i - gap)/gap + 1 = i

Comment: Greatly appreciate ur time for answering my question, thank u