# Calculating small O for this algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops

## Shell Sort Algorithm Analysis

```
void shellSort(int array[], int n){
    for (int gap = n/2; gap > 0; gap /= 2){
      for (int i = gap; i < n; i += 1) {
        int temp = array[i];
        int j;
        for (j = i; j >= gap && array[j - gap] > temp; j -= gap){
          array[j] = array[j - gap];
        }
        array[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
```

I still have difficulty in understanding how to calculate the time complexity of an algorithm. Although, I know a bit how to analyze an algorithm using big O but I don't know where to start with analyzing using small o. If u could help me, I'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What do you mean? Big O / little o are not methods of analysing an algorithm, they are notations used for the results of the analysis.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. Sorry I got it wrong

Comment: See [Shellsort - Computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Computational_complexity).

Comment: Same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509951/analyzing-shell-sort-algorithm-big-o